# HTML Advanced Search - Header part

Tags: jquery, html, css, search, advanced-search

Any idea or website to check out for search box on the header part of the website and a arrow or button to open a div to slide down to show advanced search option with some fields to search upon.

I know it's pretty simple but want to see and develop it through some examples.

--
GOK

Answer (score 1):

Ignore any examples right now but you can utilize the HTML5 `datalist` element to suggest an array of  values within a search box.

Learn more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).

Comment: datalist and a suggestive array is fine but requirement is of a icon click and slide a div to open an advanced search div which has options to filter the results.